# How to set up Vue 3 Composition API (Typescript) todo list app with reactive method

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am attempting to build a basic todo list app using Vue 3 Composition API with typescript. I previously configured the setup function for my component to use a `ref` method to handle reactivity of user input passed into the `listItems` array. Now I am attempting to refactor my setup function to use a `reactive` method, with the properties of my todo app arranged as an object. In the state object that I created, I initialized `newTodo` as an empty string, and `listItems` as a string array. The `addTodo` function is then called to push user-inputted newTodo values into the listItems array. However, with this setup I am now getting a parsing error that says an identifier is expected. This error appears to target the listItems property in the state object: `listItems: <string[]>[]`. I want to assume this means an id needs to be added to the state object in order to be appended to each list item, but am unsure how to handle this dynamically. Any idea how to resolve this? See code below:

Template

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <form @submit.prevent="addTodo()">
          <label>New ToDo</label>
          <input
              v-model="state.newTodo"
              name="newTodo"
              autocomplete="off"
          >
          <button>Add ToDo</button>
      </form>

    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="listItem in state.listItems" :key="listItem">
          <h3>{{ listItem }}</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Form',
  
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      newTodo: '',
      listItems: <string[]>[]
    })

    const addTodo = () => {
      state.listItems.push(state.newTodo)
      state.newTodo = ''
    }

    return { state, addTodo }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the generic in `reactive` like this:

```
const state = reactive<{ newTodo: string; listItems: string[] }>({
  newTodo: "",
  listItems: [],
});
```

you can also cast the `listItems` state like this :

```
const state = reactive({
  newTodo: "",
  listItems: [] as string[],
});
```

But I think the first solution is better